# Attempt to running my published asp.net mvc rc2 project resulting in unknown error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, publishing

I write a simple web application with asp.net 5 mvc rc2, every thing works fine when i run my project from vs. When i publish my project, publishing would be done without any errors, the structure of output is as follows:

[image]

When i attempts to run my application from first.exe, it stops suddenly and shows the following error:

[image]

Different stages of publishing are as follows:

[image]

Comment: I can see a stack trace. Please edit this stack trace into your question, so we can get a least a glimpse of what is going wrong.

Comment: can u tell which option you select when u click to publish?

Comment: isn't the publish output supposed to be run by IIS or a web service of some kind?

Comment: i want to run it via kestrel.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel

Comment: Take a look at the output window. VS must launch it with some arguments. not just the generated exe file

Comment: after debugging exe file with vs, it show me this error: (An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib, Additional information : The configuration file 'config' was not found and is not optional)